# OpenLayers and not well formed JSON

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, geojson, geoext, html

I am learning to use GeoExt and OpenLayers, and I want to reproduce [one of the examples](http://api.geoext.org/1.1/examples/vector-legend.html) given at the GeoExt website. The script calls a GeoJSON file containing the position of Alp summits. I downloaded it via wget and put it in data/summits.json.

I copy pasted the JavaScript file in a local folder, but when I run it in Firefox, I get a not well formed error. I got the same error with several other examples involving a JSON file. I looked for similar problems on the web, but couldn't find an answer. What am I missing?

The part of the script adding the layer from the JSON file is

```
var summits = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Summits",{
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: "data/summits.json",
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
    }),
    styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap(new OpenLayers.Style({},{rules: rules}))
});
```

I used the same bit of code in several other examples provided by the website (modulo the styleMap part) with always the same error.

Comment: I think you may need to pull the json file from a web server not a file (or at least a full URL)

Comment: Try validating your geojson: http://geojsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem may be the line 10 of your vector-legend.html, you're probably using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../script/GeoExt.js"></script>
```

but you need to download that file to your pc first with:

```
wget http://api.geoext.org/1.1/GeoExt/script/GeoExt.js
```

and then edit the HTML like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="GeoExt.js"></script>
```

or even easier, simply use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.geoext.org/1.1/GeoExt/script/GeoExt.js"></script>
```

that should do the trick. BTW, the summits.json works perfectly after using wget.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Okay, apparently the problem was elsewhere. The GeoExt.js I was using was coming from an Opengeo workshop. By using the script directly from api.geoext.org, the json appears correctly. The "not well formed" is still there though. I used @atlefren website, and it did not return any error

Comment: so probably the opengeo workshop is the problem. Please consider upvoting if the answer helped you.